# Magento 2.3.2, Amazon Sales Channel: Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page

Tags: error, magento2.3.2, form-key

*I have installed amazon sales channel v2 for magento 2.3.2 store. Now when I try to click 'Connect to amazon store' from 'Setup Amazon Store' section,*

**I'm getting error 'Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.'**

> Actually clicking 'Connect to amazon store' opens new tab with url
>   http://backend_admin/channel/amazon/account_settings_credentials_irp/merchant_id/1/key/random_key_value/
>   and it redirects to admin dashboard page with error message.
>
> So I can't proceed to 'Listing Settings' and stuck at 'Store
>   Integration'. I have checked network tab and at new tab its trying to
>   GET url
>   http://backend_adin/https:/index/index/gp/mws/registration/register.html%3Fid%3Dc2f35854....

I have made following changes-

```
max_input_vars = 200000   
max_input_time = 600  
max_execution_time = 3600  
Cleared the cache from var/cache directory.  
Cleared browser cache
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? if yes how please help me?
and sorry I'm unable to comment as I'm new here!